# Creating Static Library from a workspace

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I managed to get static libraries working and its all fine. Now that I have moved onto the proper library I want to create Im having issues. Im using cocoapods to import other files and it creates a workspace. Now the script I have for compiling no longer works and my assumption is because I am working in a framework now. I have been googling for hours trying to get an answer but all the things I have found only relate to turning a single project into a library
My questions are:
1) Is it possible to combine a workspace into one single library?
2) should I be trying to create a framework instead?
3) Is it just my script that isnt right?

```
XCODEBUILD_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
XCODEBUILD=$XCODEBUILD_PATH/xcodebuild
$XCODEBUILD -project T5Pusher.xcodeproj -target "T5Pusher" -sdk "iphoneos" -      configuration "Release" clean build
$XCODEBUILD -project T5Pusher.xcodeproj -target "T5Pusher" -sdk "iphonesimulator" -   configuration "Release" clean build
lipo -create -output "build/libT5Pusher.a" "build/Release-iphoneos/libT5Pusher.a" "build/Release-iphonesimulator/libT5Pusher.a"
```

also tried this

```
XCODEBUILD_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
XCODEBUILD=$XCODEBUILD_PATH/xcodebuild
$XCODEBUILD -workspace T5Pusher.xcworkspace -scheme "T5Pusher" -sdk "iphoneos" -      configuration "Release" clean build
$XCODEBUILD -workspace T5Pusher.xcworkspace -scheme "T5Pusher" -sdk "iphonesimulator" -   configuration "Release" clean build
lipo -create -output "build/libT5Pusher.a" "build/Release-iphoneos/libT5Pusher.a" "build/Release-iphonesimulator/libT5Pusher.a"
```

The errors I get are

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
Libtool build/PusherTest.build/Release-iphoneos/PusherTest.build/Objects-    normal/armv7/libPusherTest.a normal armv7
Libtool build/PusherTest.build/Release-iphoneos/PusherTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/libPusherTest.a normal armv7s
(2 failures)
lipo: can't open input file: build/Release-iphoneos/libPusherTest.a (No such file or directory)
Showing first 200 notices only
```

and for the second, the build succeeds but the library (.a) files are never created so it cannot combine them

Comment: In what way is it not working? Is there an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. You have to use the command:

```
pod install --no-integrate
```

when installing the pod. This will not create a workspace and allow the use of the script

```
XCODEBUILD_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
XCODEBUILD=$XCODEBUILD_PATH/xcodebuild
$XCODEBUILD -project T5Pusher.xcodeproj -target "T5Pusher" -sdk "iphoneos" -        configuration "Release" clean build
$XCODEBUILD -project T5Pusher.xcodeproj -target "T5Pusher" -sdk "iphonesimulator" -   configuration "Release" clean build
lipo -create -output "build/libT5Pusher.a" "build/Release-iphoneos/libT5Pusher.a" "build/Release-iphonesimulator/libT5Pusher.a"
```

Then to set the config file for pods:

-Go to project editor -> info -> configuration

-Set the target to use pods.xconfig file for debug and release

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue myself and found that if I specified the output directories and then told lipo to look there then it worked while still letting me use the workspace.  The may be different in Xcode 5 but when I use it as a custom build phase then it works without specifying the output directories and I only have to direct lipo to ${BUILD_DIR} to find the generated files.

```
$XCODEBUILD -project T5Pusher.xcodeproj \
 -target "T5Pusher" \
 -sdk "iphoneos" \ 
 -configuration "Release"
 OBJROOT=${env_variable_to_some_directory}/Obj.root \
 SYMROOT=${env_variable_to_some_directory}/Sym.root \
 DSTROOT=${env_variable_to_some_directory}/Dst.root \
 clean build
```